# cannot get caller id number, destination number & call time in pami package with php

Tags: php

I am using **marcelog/PAMI** package with php. the configurations and connection are done. now I want to get the following information 
 1. For example, Extension 201 when rings. (then I want to get Source and Destination Numbers)
 2. Ext 201, Pick up call. ( call time)
 3. Ext 201, Hang up call ( total Time of call).

i am using this code

```
try
{
    $options = array(
    'host' => '1.1.1.1',
    'scheme' => 'tcp://',
    'port' => 122,
    'username' => 'user',
    'secret' => 'pass',
    'connect_timeout' => 1000000,
    'read_timeout' => 1000000
);
    $a = new ClientImpl($options);
    // Registering a closure
    //$client->registerEventListener(function ($event) {
    //});
    // Register a specific method of an object for event listening
    //$client->registerEventListener(array($listener, 'handle'));
    // Register an IEventListener:
    $a->registerEventListener(new A());
    $a->open();
    $time = time();
    while(true)//(time() - $time) < 60) // Wait for events.
    {
        usleep(1000); // 1ms delay
        // Since we declare(ticks=1) at the top, the following line is not necessary
        // $a->process();
    $response = json_decode(json_encode($a->process()),true);
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($response);

    }
```

please if anyone knows about this please share your answer. 
Thanks...

Comment: We need more details to help you out. Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: In addition to above comment, please take the [tour] as a new user. Also, please format your code according to PSR conventions, it makes it easier for others to read and understand.